# Can I change column name from a select statement to the parameter passed in from a stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a stored procedure takes in a parameter `@phonename` and I want to find out the property of the phone from the database. After I get the property from the database I would like to change the title of the column `"Property"` to the phone name that gets passed in from the stored procedure. For example, can I do

```
Select property as @phonename
from property
join phone on property.Phid = phone.Phid
where phoneid = (select phid from phone where name = @phonename)
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, it is posible, although not recommended...

You could use dynamic sql:

```
DECLARE @command varchar(1000)
DECLARE @phonename varchar(100)
SET @phonename = 'Aaron'
SET @command = 'SELECT myColumn AS ' + @phonename + ' FROM myTable WHERE name = ' + @phonename
EXEC (@command)
```

See: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1160/execute-dynamic-sql-commands-in-sql-server/

**NOTE:**
If your planning to use something like this in a production environment please think about the possibilites of **SQL Injection**. You might be safer by applying those name changes in your application code instead of in SQL.

See: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp